# Maintaining the history of values in table/ track the changes of table by date

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, history

Following is my table structure:

```
PROJECT_ID      MODULE_ID      PASS FAIL RETEST NOT_EXECUTED TOTAL
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_1   10   5    2      2            19
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_2   20   5    5      0            30
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_3   30   5    2      0            37
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_4   40   5    7      2            54
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_5   50   5    2      0            57
```

And every day I will update the numbers in Pass, fail, retest, net executed and total column of this table. I am doing this using a webpage (as front end for both viewing and updating the table).

Now the problem arises when I want to see the status as of 2 days before. To be more clear, data as of Mar-09 will look like:

```
PROJECT_ID      MODULE_ID      PASS FAIL RETEST NOT_EXECUTED TOTAL
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_1   10   5    2      2            19
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_2   20   5    5      0            30
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_3   30   5    2      0            37
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_4   40   5    7      2            54
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_5   50   5    2      0            57
```

And on Mar-10 I updated the values in table as

```
PROJECT_ID      MODULE_ID      PASS FAIL RETEST NOT_EXECUTED TOTAL
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_1   20   5    2      2            29
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_2   20   5    5      5            35
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_3   30   5    12     0            47
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_4   40   5    7      2            54
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_5   60   5    2      0            67
```

and on Mar-11 I want to see the status as of Mar-09 which is:

```
PROJECT_ID      MODULE_ID      PASS FAIL RETEST NOT_EXECUTED TOTAL
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_1   10   5    2      2            19
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_2   20   5    5      0            30
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_3   30   5    2      0            37
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_4   40   5    7      2            54
TEST_1         TEST_1_MOD_5   50   5    2      0            57
```

I have a non-feasible solution which is to add a new column in the table called `'DATE_UPDATED'` and I should insert new rows for each module everyday. But I'm afraid this will increase the table space.

Is this the best practice? or do we have any other better solution? Please help!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are there more `PROJECT_ID` values aside from `TEST_1`? Why are afraid of disk space? Are you hosting the website yourself or is it a limitation if you are hosting somewhere else? How many (or average) records everyday you generate in your table?

Comment: Are there any limitations about dates? Do you need statistics only for the NOW()-2 days? Or statistics for all days in the past? If you need stats for 2 days only just add 2 more sets of the same columns (MODULE_ID_1_DAY_BEFORE, PASS_1_DAY_BEFORE, ..., MODULE_ID_2_DAYS_BEFORE, PASS_2_DAYS_BEFORE) and on update move data from current columns set to the previous days' columns

Comment: Dear @Edper : yes, More projects will be added in future. Again yes, I am hosting it as a website. On an average status of 20 projects needs to be updated. Each projects may have 10+ modules. so, 20 projects x 10 moduls a day means 200 rows per day. Which will give burden to my server and also delay the data processing while showing the result.

Comment: Dear @StanislavL Dates are dynamic. Its not like Now() -2 days. I should be able to query for any past date for which the data is available

Comment: In this case you definitely need DATE_UPDATED column in the table

Comment: as i mentioned earlier, Each projects may have 10+ modules. so, 20 projects x 10 moduls a day means 200 rows per day. Which will give burden to my server and also delay the data processing while showing the result. Do we have any better solution? @StanislavL

Comment: If you need stats for any possible day you have to store numbers for each date. 200 rows per day isn't problem at all.